# Can not See "Documents On Nick's iPad" device when plugging my iPad into my Ubuntu 14.10 System to view app documents

Tags: 14.04, sync, ios

Whenever i plug in and mount my iPad to my computer (iPad running iOS 8.1.2 and computer running Ubuntu 14.10) all i see is a "Nick's iPad" device. I am supposed to but do not see a "Documents on Nick's iPad" device. Please help as i need to access those files. I have libimobiledevice installed and i have been told to reboot my iPad. I have rebooted both iPad and computer but no avail. it still doesnt work.

Thanks!